# How to initialize an array in Eiffel

Tags: arrays, initialization, eiffel

How to initialize an array with a list of numbers in Eiffel?

In C it would be like this:

int foo[] = {2, 3, 5, 7, 10, 87, 72, 67, 1, 0};

Comment: Did you try to read "the docs" first? "Manifest array" would be a keyword to the solution.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Like This:

```
make
    local
        foo: ARRAY [INTEGER]
    do
        foo := << 2, 3, 5, 7, 10, 87, 72, 67, 1, 0 >>
    end
```